# Validate form pulled in via ajax

Tags: ajax, validation

Working on a small website, and the index page, pulls contact.php page in via ajax. All works good.

But validation will not work, just get page refresh.

If I view the file via its direct link, it validates no problem.

I read that using: .load insetead of .ready is the way to go, on the validation js

like:

```
$("#formDiv").load("/Path/To/Form", function() { 
$("#formDiv form").validate();
});
```

But I just cannot get it to play ball.

My setup is:
index.php with jquery loading in the head.

In footer validate.js and my validation rules js file.

In the contact.php page I have just  ---- content -----

Just a tad bemused what I am doing wrong.

The test page ( using document ready for the js because test isnt fired from ajax request )

( click the Circular Book a Pool Inspection ) link

This pulls in ajax page contact.php ( Which I am not sure if I have done correctly , as I havent added head body and html tags or any js ) I have all this loading in the index page

The test.php I have created which works, has all js stuff loaded etc for testing

Could someone shed some light as to what I am doing wrong please.